# Cuando haga login, lanzar un componente ANGULARJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Quiero hacer, que cuando haga login, lance otro componente

about.html

```
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h3>Login</h3>
  <!-- Form to get username & Password -->
   <form>
      <label>Username:</label><input type="text" ng-model="username" /></br></br>
      <label></label>Password:</label><input type="password" ng-model="password"></br>
      <button  type="submit" ng-click="submit()">login</button>
  </form>
  <div id="suss"></div>

<!-- Displaying the Array using ng-repeat -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="..\js\angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="..\js\about.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

about.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';


  $scope.submit=function()
  {
     if($scope.username=='wallx' && $scope.password=='123')
     {
    alert("welcome "+$scope.username);

     }else{
       alert("Invalid Login");
     }
  }
});
```

componente que quiero lanzar cunado haga un login correcto

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>

  </head>
<body>
     <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/info.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="ContactController">
    <form>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name</td> 
<td><input type="text" name="name" ng-model="newcontact.name"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" ng-model="newcontact.email"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Phone</td> 
<td><input type="text" name="phone" ng-model="newcontact.phone"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" ng-model="newcontact.id" /></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="saveContact()" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
    </form>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
    <td>{{ contact.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.phone }}</td>
    <td>
        <a  href="#" ng-click="edit(contact.id)">edit</a> | 
        <a href="#" ng-click="delete(contact.id)">delete</a>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Como estas manejando el routing de la web? desde el back-end con algun framework o desde el front-end con ng-route o ui-route?

Answer (score 0):

$location.path('/home');

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.name = 'World';


$scope.submit=function()
  {
 if($scope.username=='wallx' && $scope.password=='123')
 {
alert("welcome "+$scope.username);

  //si esl usuario se ha longeado, lanzar a otro componente
    $location.path('/home');
 }else{
   alert("Invalid Login");
 }
}
});
```